# Summing tables that include text in Matlab

Tags: matlab, function, data-manipulation

Given the example table:

```
A = table({'test2';'test1';'test2';'test3';'test1'},...
[0.71;2.05;0.35;0.82;1.57],[0.23;0.12;0.18;0.23;0.41])

A = 
 Var1      Var2    Var3
_______    ____    ____

'test2'    0.71    0.23
'test1'    2.05    0.12
'test2'    0.35    0.18
'test3'    0.82    0.23
'test1'    1.57    0.41
```

How do I create a last row that contains the sum of the column without having to group using 'GroupingVariables' or by specifying the variables directly (i.e. would need to simply sum accross the entire table for those columns that are numerical)?
I then want to create another table (B) where each entry is divided by the sum of the corresponding column (i.e. to create a percentage value). However, not including a 'GroupingVariables' argument returns:

> Undefined function 'sum' for input arguments of type 'cell'

and array type manipulation is not working for tables...

Comment: Last row, for example would be ['sum'  '5.5'   '1.17']. Then table B would have each Var2 divided by 5.5 and each Var3 divided by 1.17. My table is quite large so I would need to be able to do it without specifiying the columns directly or mapping them manually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### To compute the sum of each numeric column:

First define an index for the numeric columns

```
>> ind = [2 3];
```

If you don't know which columns are numeric: compute a logical index `ind` as follows

```
>> ind = table2array(varfun(@isnumeric, A));
```

Then you can convert the columns specified by `ind` to a numeric array using [`table2array`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table2array.html) and do the sum over each column:

```
>> sum(table2array(A(:,ind)),1)
ans =
    5.5000    1.1700
```

You also could use [`varfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varfun.html), which lets you choose table output (default)

```
>> varfun(@sum, A(:,ind))
ans = 
    sum_Var2    sum_Var3
    ________    ________
    5.5         1.17
```

or numeric array output

```
>> varfun(@sum, A(:,ind), 'outputformat', 'uniform')
ans =
    5.5000    1.1700
```

#### To normalize each numeric column to sum 1:

Use `varfun` with an anonymous function:

```
>> B = A;
>> ind = table2array(varfun(@isnumeric, A));
>> A(:,ind) = varfun(@(x) x./sum(x), A(:,ind));
>> A = 
       Var1        Var2       Var3  
      _______    ________    _______
      'test2'     0.12909    0.19658
      'test1'     0.37273    0.10256
      'test2'    0.063636    0.15385
      'test3'     0.14909    0.19658
      'test1'     0.28545    0.35043
```

Comment: Yes exactly- however I would not be able to specify the columns directly/ manually.

Comment: Nice I just learned about `varfun` very useful thanks for that!